# how to solve the class value initialize every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, webforms

I'm trying to write a caculator as a website,

I set 2 variables in my class to store the number,

but everytime I click a "+" or "-" button,

the variable go back to the inital stamtement.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int choice = 0;
    Boolean caluOrNot = false;
    double before, after;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.caluOrNot == false)
        {
            if (txtResult.Text.ToString() == "0")
            {
                txtResult.Text = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                txtResult.Text += "1";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtResult.Text = "1";
        }
    }

    protected void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    protected void Btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    protected void Btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    protected void BtnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text += ".";
    }

    protected void BtnJia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.choice = 1;
        this.caluOrNot = true;
        before = Double.Parse(txtResult.Text.ToString());
        txtCalu.Text = before.ToString() + "+";

    }

    protected void BtnJen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void BtnCheng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void BtnChu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text = "0";
        this.choice = 0;
    }

    protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a;
        switch (this.choice)
        {
            case 1:
                a = before + after;
                txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
                break;
            case 2:
                a = before - after;
                txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
                break;
            case 3:
                a = before * after;
                txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
                break;
            case 4:
                a = before / after;
                txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

As th code, everytime I click `btnJia` will trigger the onclick method `BtnJia_Click`

The choice will be set to "1" and `caculOrNot` set to true, but the values change back to 0 and false when the `BtnJia_Click` finish.

How can I  solve it?

Comment: I can't compiled your code..`protected void Btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`, where is `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET when you click BtnJia_Click everything starts from beginning. So you need to store values of *caculOrNot* and *choice* at session and read them from session when you need them. Here is an example:

```
protected void BtnJia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.choice = 1;
    this.caluOrNot = true;
    before = Double.Parse(txtResult.Text.ToString());
    txtCalu.Text = before.ToString() + "+";

    //Store them in Session
    Session["choice"] = this.choice;
    Session["caluOrNot"] = this.caluOrNot;
}

protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read them from Session when you need
    if(Session["choice"] != null)
    {
        this.choice = Convert.ToInt32(Session["choice"]);
    }

    double a;
    switch (this.choice)
    {
        case 1:
            a = before + after;
            txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
            break;
        case 2:
            a = before - after;
            txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
            break;
        case 3:
            a = before * after;
            txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
            break;
        case 4:
            a = before / after;
            txtResult.Text = a.ToString();
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }

    }
}
```

Read more about Session State [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).